# converting numbers on y axis to string with K for thousand d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i am using d3.js charts to plot y axis and x axis. It's working fine, but the values in y axis you can say range is say 0 to 10000 and I want if the number is greater than thousand it will come with K.
if the number is 1000 it will show 1K, for 15000 it will show on y axis ticks 15K.

How to do that? I am not able to manupulate `y.domain` and range functions for the string values.

```js
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([ height, 0 ]);
y.domain([
  0,
  d3.max(cities, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.count; }); })
]);
```

Comment: Post an example of what you tried so far in http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From [API Reference](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Formatting.md), we see `d3.formatPrefix`

```
var prefix = d3.formatPrefix(1.21e9);
console.log(prefix.symbol); // "G"
console.log(prefix.scale(1.21e9)); // 1.21
```

We can use it this way

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .ticks(5)
    .tickFormat(function (d) {
        var prefix = d3.formatPrefix(d);
        return prefix.scale(d) + prefix.symbol;
    })
    .orient("left");
```

However, in case this is exactly what you mean, we can simplify using `d3.format("s")`

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .ticks(5)
    .tickFormat(d3.format("s"))
    .orient("left");
```

Answer (score 9):

You're looking for `tickFormat` on the axis object.

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 800)
    .attr("height", 100);

//Create the Scale we will use for the Axis
var axisScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 2000])
    .range([0, 600]);

//Create the Axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(axisScale)
    .tickFormat(function (d) {
      if ((d / 1000) >= 1) {
        d = d / 1000 + "K";
      }
      return d;
    });

var xAxisGroup = svgContainer.append("g")
    .call(xAxis);
```

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/3CmV6/2/

This will give you what you want, but I recommend checking the suggestion from robermorales to use `d3.format('s')` .

Answer (score 8):

This is what i implemented

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).ticks(5).
tickFormat(function (d) {
    var array = ['','k','M','G','T','P'];
    var i=0;
    while (d > 1000)
    {
        i++;
        d = d/1000;
    }

    d = d+' '+array[i];

    return d;}).
orient("left");
```

it will work for even more than thousand ...

Comment: I needed to improve y-axis on network traffic graph (sorta' like an MRTG graph.  I used this solution to get bps, Kbps, Mbps, Gbps, etc. by overridng the tickFormat method, using "bps","Kbps", Mbps", etc. in the array named array. These are the norm for speeds in Networking, while Storage sometimes uses MBps (megabytes per second), different by a factor of 8.

Answer (score 1):

A concise approach:

```
var myTickFormat = function (d) {//Logic to reduce big numbers
  var limits = [1000000000000000, 1000000000000, 1000000000, 1000000, 1000];
  var shorteners = ['Q','T','B','M','K'];
  for(var i in limits) {
    if(d > limits[i]) {
      return (d/limits[i]).toFixed() + shorteners[i];
    }
  }
  return d;
};

spenderRowChart
    .xAxis().ticks(3)
    .tickFormat(myTickFormat);
```

**This returns `1K` for `1000`, 1M for `1,000,000`, and so on.**
 Note: Beyond quadrillion, you may wanna go through [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
      axis: {
                y: {
                    tick: {
                        format: d3.format("$.2s")
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: the best answer

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to edit the labels on the ticks you can use the [tickFormat](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickFormat) function.

For example, your y axis function would look something like this:

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(function(tickVal) {
        return tickVal >= 1000 ? tickVal/1000 + "K" : tickVal;
    });
```

Then you just have to call it. Assuming you have a variable called svg that references your svg chart:

```
svg.append("g)
    .call(yAxis);
```

To make things a little clearer I've created [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GAQAv/) based on [this tutorial](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/axes/), adapted to display axis tick labels in the way you describe above if the value is greater than or equal to 1000. If you run it a few times you will see how different axis values are handled.