# How to display one million in dimple measure axis as 1000k instead of 1m?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

We are displaying price value in y axis for a chart using dimpleJs. When the price more than 1 million, its automatically converted to 1m while displaying in the chart. I would like the millions to be displayed in terms of thousands or lakhs / hundreds of thousands, see [Indian Numbering System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system). How to do it? I have searched and tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15494605/3951718) answer 
 but it doesn't seem to work. Below is my code snippet:

```
const yAxis = chart.addMeasureAxis('y', 'total');
yAxis.tickFormat = function(d) {
  let result = d;
  if ((d / 1000) >= 1) {
    result = d / 1000 + 'K';
  }
  return result;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at johnkiernander's answer on this thread:  https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/421

Dimple just passes a string to d3.js's format function, so you can't pass a function to tickformat, you should be able to override the `_getformat` function like this:

```
  yAxis._getFormat = function() {
    return function(d) {
      let result = d;
      if ((d / 1000) >= 1) {
        result = d / 1000 + 'K';
      }
      return result;
    };
  };
```